Assign swim-lanes per topic instead of per team
Azure DevOps offers Delivery Plans. These are essentially swim-lanes of planned work, per team.
I am looking for a way to switch to swim-lanes per topic, so:

cross team dependencies become more clear
teams have better insight in mutual dependencies

Default ADO view:
Team 1: work item A ------------
                  |
Team 2: ----------+> work item B

Desired ADO view:
Topic 1: work item A > work item B
Topic 2: ...

The MS documentation is very limited.
Any extensions I've encountered - like  product plan roadmap templates - seem to have the problem that ADO is no longer the single source of truth.
What options/best practices are out there to generate cross team delivery plans, using ADO?

queries ?
extentions ?
... ?


Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Refer to this doc: Review team delivery plans in Azure Boards

Use the visualization options provided by the Delivery Plans feature of Azure Boards to review the schedule of stories or features that your teams plan to deliver. A delivery plan shows the scheduled work items by sprint (iteration path) of selected teams against a calendar view.

Currently, Azure DevOps Delivery Plans feature only supports displaying the calendar view by selecting a team.
I am afraid that there are no out-of-box feature or extensions can create the  delivery plan based on the topic.
When you using Queries feature in Azure DevOps, it can show dependencies between work items across teams. But it cannot interact with the teams like the delivery plan feature. It has many limitations.
At the same time, there are no other extensions that can fully meet your needs.
I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community to report this feature.
